# gform_after_submission does not fire after nested entry form submission // Gravityforms

Tags: nested-forms, gravityforms

I have been working on a form (form_id_3) / subform (nested form_id_2).

On nested form, each time entry is submitted, i would like to trigger all flow steps (webhook will fill some fiedls in nested form.

Tried code below without success

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'my_nested_form_action' );

function my_nested_form_action( $entry ) {

  if ( $entry['form_id'] == 2 ) {
    $nested_entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $entry['form_id'] );
    foreach ( $nested_entries as $nested_entry ) {
      GFAPI::run_workflow_steps( $nested_entry['id'] );
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me say what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to say, this is flow pluggin for gravityforms.
Also tried with "GFAPI::run_workflow_steps()", using entry id and step id.

add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'my_nested_form_action' );

function my_nested_form_action( $form_id ) {
  if ( $form_id == 2 ) {
    $nested_entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id );
    foreach ( $nested_entries as $nested_entry ) {
      $entry_id = $nested_entry['id'];
      $workflow_id = GFAPI::get_workflow_id( $entry_id );

      GFAPI::run_workflow_steps( $entry_id, $workflow_id );
    }
  }
}